# VBA Error 1004. Method 'Range of object'_Global failed

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried searching the repository for the solution to the above problem but my VBA shills are rudimentary and the answer eludes me. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

When running the code below it errows at the following line:

```
PartNumber = Range("E" & myrow).Value
```

The code is Run time error '1004':
Method 'Range of object'_Global failed.

```
Dim objDrv      As Object
Dim strMsg      As String


For Each objDrv In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").drives
    Select Case objDrv.DriveType
        Case 0: strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine & objDrv.driveletter & ": Unknown"
        Case 1: strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine & objDrv.driveletter & ": Removable Drive"
        Case 2: strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine & objDrv.driveletter & ": Hard Disk Drive"
        Case 3: strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine & objDrv.driveletter & ": Network Drive"
        'Case 4: strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine & objDrv.driveletter & ": CDROM Drive"
        Case 5: strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine & objDrv.driveletter & ": RAM Disk Drive"
    End Select
Next

Set objDrv = Nothing
'MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation

Dim sdcard As String

sdcard = InputBox( _
"Confirm which drive you wnat to create the romdata directory in." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Drives Found:" _
& strMsg & vbNewLine, _
"Choose SD Card Letter.", _
"Type your file name here")
If Len(sdcard) = 1 Then
MsgBox "You have selcted the " & sdcard & " drive."
        ElseIf Len(sdcard) >= 2 Then
    MsgBox " Too many characters"
    ElseIf Len(sdcard) <= 0 Then
End If

Dim myLoop As Integer

For myLoop = 7 To 9000

    If Len(Range("I" & myLoop).Value) > 0 Then

Dim aTemp As String
Dim bTemp As String
Dim dTemp As String
Dim eTemp As String
Dim subdir As String
Dim PartNumber As String
Dim otemp As String
Dim ptemp As String

aTemp = sdcard & Chr(58) & "\romdata\"
a1temp = sdcard & Chr(58) & "\romdata"
bTemp = strMsg
PartNumber = Range("E" & myrow).Value
otemp = PartNumber & ".fwu"
ptemp = "\" & PartNumber
dTemp = ActiveWorkbook.pATH
eTemp = "\Firmware files"
subdir = "\Firmware Files\" & PartNumber & "\" & otemp

MsgBox "The full path to this file is " & dTemp & "\" & PartNumber

If dir(dTemp & subdir) = "" Then
MsgBox "The file you have selected, (" & PartNumber & ") will not be copied." & vbNewLine & _
"Please check the file is suitable for uploading to the device using an SD card." & vbNewLine & _
"(It should have a .fwu extension.)"
Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox "The file " & otemp & " is being copied to " & aTemp

 If Len(dir(aTemp, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir a1temp

End If


FileCopy dTemp & subdir, aTemp & otemp
```

Answer (score 3):

`myrow` is never defined in the snippet you have posted. Define it before using it.

Comment: +1 looks like `myLoop` might have been the intended name. Adding `Option Explicit` at the top of the module would have caught this

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. Alexandre, I'm glad you managed to help me see the wood through the trees.